# Facing compilation issue while upgrading Deployer extension to Web 8.5

Tags: deployer-extension

I am trying to upgrade Deployer extension code from Tridion 2013 to SDL Web 8.5. I am not sure what all Java apis need to be upgraded, I tried with **deployer-api-8.5.0-1013.jar** but not able to resolve some classes and getting compilation errors, i.e.

```
import com.tridion.configuration.Configuration;
import com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import com.tridion.deployer.Module;
import com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.TransportPackage;
```

Please help me to figure out what api i should add to Maven dependency.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade your deployer extension project with following 8.5 deployer jars dependencies to work for SDL Web 8.5

> - cd_common_config-8.5.0-1009.jar
> - cd_common_config_legacy-8.5.0-1009.jar
> - cd_common_util-8.5.0-1009.jar
> - cd_core-8.5.0-1011.jar
> - cd_datalayer-8.5.0-1014.jar
> - cd_datalayer_extension-8.5.0-1014.jar
> - cd_model-8.5.0-1013.jar
> - cd_tcdl-8.5.0-1014.jar
> - commons-codec-1.10.jar
> - deployer-model-8.5.0-1014.jar
> - deployer-web-extension-8.5.0-1013.jar
> - httpclient-4.5.2.jar
> - httpcore-4.4.5.jar
> - jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
> - jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
> - jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
> - logback-classic-1.1.7.jar
> - logback-core-1.1.7.jar
> - slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Velu, Thanks for the answer, i'll check with mentioned jars and let you know

Comment: Adding Jars fixed compilation issue, thanks for information.

Answer (score 2):

It depends which classes you use in your code, for example, my Deployer extension (custom Module) is working with the dependencies listed below.

Just another point, in Tridion 2013 (SP1) you could create custom Processors, but they are no longer supported. Meaning, that if your old code has any, you will need to change the logic for Web 8.5, you cannot simply rebuild your code against the new jars.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl</groupId>
    <artifactId>cd-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl</groupId>
    <artifactId>cd-common-util</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl</groupId>
    <artifactId>cd-common-config-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl</groupId>
    <artifactId>deployer-web-extension</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl</groupId>
    <artifactId>deployer-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl</groupId>
    <artifactId>cd-model</artifactId>
    <version>8.5</version>
</dependency>                
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @Atila, Thanks for answer and suggestion on Processor, will check if there is any custom processor.